# Entity Framework and Text

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know why I get an error in the following code ?

```
Employee objEmp = new Employee();
objEmp.HREmpId = txtHREmpId.Text;
```

Does not contain definition for 'Text' .Maybe it is an older Entity Framework version .

Currently working on Visual Studio 2015 , ASP.NET Web Application

Comment: What is `txtHREmpId`? And how is Entity framework related to this?

Comment: I think you want to get the Text value from asp.net TextBox control. But it looks like the variable txtHREmpId is something else. that is why @GertArnold ask you 'what is txtHREmpId'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
bjEmp.HREmpId = txtHREmpId.ToString();
```

is Text a property? so check if it is (get; set;)

Maybe you should add what is the types of the properties HREmpId and Text for help you better.